# Dedicated Debian Package Server

Tags: debian, package-management, repository

We've got a series of debs for different projects and different environments to install them in:  dev, build/test qa (less formal), qa (formal), and production.

I would really like to create a system by which I can in some way indicate what version of each package belongs in each environment, and then have them automatically deploy.

I've debated using a local debian repository but that's a lot more than seems needed.  And, I've wondered if I could create a private repository just for the debs that I have, much akin to Ubuntu's PPA.  I know that we use CF Engine for deploying and managing configurations on servers, though I'm not sure if its made for deploying debian packages.

Is there a right way to go about this?

**Update** It seems that CF Engine [can be used](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/398) for managing debian packages.

Answer (score 0):

Use a local repository for each environment.  mini-dinstall is a simple enough repository manager, but you will have to move packages between repositories manually.